# How can I use predicates in Python

Tags: python, predicate, declarative

I want to use python in a more declarative way, using predicates as much as possible to simplify things, but I'm having trouble seeing how to do that "simply" in python.

For example, when counting items in a list I want to be able to pass in a predicate, like this:

```
mylist.count(lambda x: x.contains("f"))
```

to count items in the list that contain and "f".

I can see how to do this with itertools:

```
sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x.contains("f") else 0, l))
```

but that's worse than a for loop. Am I missing something or does Python just not allow for this kind of expression?

Comment: `sum(x.contains("f") for x in l)`; `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and a sequence of `bool` values can be summed directly.

Answer (score 2):

The "simplest" (or at least, most decomposable) way would use `operator.methodcaller` along with `sum`.

```
from operator import methodcaller

p = methodcaller("contains", "f")
sum(map(p, l))
```

This works because `contains` returns an instance of `bool`, which is a subclass of `int`.

You can also use a generator expression to create a sequence of `1`s from a filtered iterable.

```
sum(1 for x in l if x.contains("f"))
```

Comment: Or `sum(x.contains("f") for x in l)`

Comment: Ugh, how did I forget to include that i my answer?